# pandas get difference of 2 times assuming if end_time is lower than start_time it is the next day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Assuming this is my dataframe:

```
date        start_time end_time
1/1/2018     20:00       21:00
1/1/2018     23:00       1:00
```

I want to add another column, named `duration` which is obviously `end_time - start_time`

My problem is that if I write something like:

```
pd.to_datetime(train_2.end_time,format='%H:%M:%S')-pd.to_timedelta(train_2.start_time))
```

It thinks that the second line is negative (as 23:00>1:00), while it's really positive as 1:00 refers to the next day (1/2/2018), so I want the duration to be 2 hours.

How can I achieve such a result?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try of subtracting by converting to datestamp, and for all the exception cases of negative values add extra day duration

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end_time) -  pd.to_datetime(df.start_time)
df.loc[df.duration.dt.total_seconds() <0,'duration'] += pd.Timedelta(1,'D')
```

Out:

```
date    start_time  end_time    duration
0   1/1/2018    20:00   21:00   01:00:00
1   1/1/2018    23:00   1:00    02:00:00
```